# kendo ui on editable pop up window load event

Tags: kendo-ui

Is there a load window event on kendo ui grid editable popup window. I want to write some code when the window has loaded successfully

```
.Editable(ed => ed.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp).TemplateName("CustomEditors/CustomEditor").Window(w => w.Title("Account").Name("MyCustomWindow").Resizable().Width(800).Height(600)))
```

In this case when the MycustomWindow is loaded and the CustomEditor view is rendered, then I want to write some code

Is this possible ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [Edit](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/grid#events-edit) event of the Grid

```
.Events(ev=>ev.Edit("onEdit")
...

<script>
function onEdit(e){
    //your logic goes here
}
</script>
```

Comment: Just another question related to the popup window. Is there like a "pop up window has loaded now" event?

Comment: hasLoaded or wasActivated. Edit is triggered when the window was laoded, you might need to look at the activate event.

Comment: Did this work at one point ? The Edit event for me fires when I expand the details view, and I can't get an event to fire when the 'edit' button is clicked, unless I add one, which then fires before the window is visible, not after